# function prototype in perl

Tags: perl, subroutine, subroutine-prototypes

I am trying to create the subroutine mypush with similar functionality of inbuilt push function, but the below code is not working properly.

```
    @planets = ('mercury', 'venus', 'earth', 'mars');
    myPush(@planets,"Test");

    sub myPush (\@@) {
         my $ref = shift;
         my @bal = @_;
         print "\@bal :  @bal\nRef : @{$ref}\n";
         #...
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At this line:

```
    myPush(@planets,"Test");
```

Perl hasn't yet seen the prototype, so it can't apply it. (If you turn on warnings, which you always should, you'll get a message that `main::myPush() called too early to check prototype`.)

You can either create your subroutine *before* you use it:

```
    sub myPush (\@@) {
         my $ref = shift;
         my @bal = @_;
         print "\@bal :  @bal\nRef : @{$ref}\n";
         #...
    }

    @planets = ('mercury', 'venus', 'earth', 'mars');
    myPush(@planets,"Test");
```

or else at least pre-declare it with its prototype:

```
    sub myPush (\@@);

    @planets = ('mercury', 'venus', 'earth', 'mars');
    myPush(@planets,"Test");

    sub myPush (\@@) {
         my $ref = shift;
         my @bal = @_;
         print "\@bal :  @bal\nRef : @{$ref}\n";
         #...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure of the functions and their names, you can just put an ampersand before the call:

```
@planets = ('mercury', 'venus', 'earth', 'mars');
&myPush(@planets,"Test");

sub myPush (\@@) {
     my $ref = shift;
     my @bal = @_;
     print "\@bal :  @bal\nRef : @{$ref}\n";
     #...
}
```